# Error code: Wsl/Service/CreateInstance/MountVhd/ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Tags: windows-11, wsl2

I have uninstalled wsl on my windows 11 and trying to re-install using wsl --install. After restart i am getting following error

```
    Failed to attach disk 'C:\Users\<User>\AppData\Local\Packages\CanonicalGroupLimited.Ubuntu_79rhkp1fndgsc\LocalState\ext4.vhdx' to WSL2: The system cannot find the file specified.
Error code: Wsl/Service/CreateInstance/MountVhd/ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
```

Answer (score 56, accepted):

From the [WSL Github issue on the topic](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/8710) and the resulting [discussion thread](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/discussions/8729):

1. List the distributions installed, by running following in PowerShell.

   ```
   wsl -l
   ```
2. Unregister the distribution. Replace the "Ubuntu" below with your distribution name found in Step #1:

   **NOTE: THIS COMMAND WILL COMPLETELY UNINSTALL YOUR WSL DISTRO.**

   ```
   wsl --unregister Ubuntu
   ```
3. Launch the Ubuntu (or other distribution) which was installed using Microsoft Store

Comment: Right on the money @kshashank! Much appreciated ^^

Comment: Just a heads up: this command will completely uninstall your WSL distro... I learned this the hard way.

Comment: It's a terrible solution and no warning given about it uninstalling your distro. Thankfully I was not stupid enough to do it.

Comment: @AndrewS Were you able to fix it without losing the distro. I agree this solution is terrible

Comment: @warmwhisky, I gave up and installed wsl on my new Windows 11 machine leaving my older Windows 10 broken.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple issues on Github regarding this problem:
[This one](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/11288), [that one](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/11290), [and this other](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/11069).

[The solution](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/11069#issuecomment-1918008956) is to download the installer and downgrade manually to another version: `2.1.4.0` fixed it for me. You don't have to completely remove your WSL distro.

You can find the releases [here](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/releases).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).