# wsl ubuntu fails after microsoft store update

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

After using the Microsoft Store app to update all apps (including WSL), WSL fails to run when run without admin privilege.

```
Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Try the new cross-platform PowerShell https://aka.ms/pscore6

PS C:\Users\mslin> wsl
Element not found.
Error code: Wsl/ERROR_NOT_FOUND
```

If I run PowerShell with administrator privileges then I can start it by typing `wsl`.
Ubuntu is still intact.
In the following I launched PowerShell with admin privilege, otherwise this command would also fail:

```
Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Try the new cross-platform PowerShell https://aka.ms/pscore6

PS C:\Windows\system32> wsl -l
Windows Subsystem for Linux Distributions:
Ubuntu (Default)
```

What should I do to fix this?

Comment: [This](https://superuser.com/questions/1816599/wsl-update-element-not-found) seems like a likely duplicate.  Can you [edit] your question to include additional vital information to answer your question? [This](https://superuser.com/questions/1758361/error-code-wsl-service-createinstance-mountvhd-error-file-not-found) actually appears to be a better duplicate

Comment: [Edit] your question to include your [WSL logs](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/8401).  Without the logs we cannot help you

Comment: @Ramhound the issue is not related
Happend today for me after a scheduled winupdate
To access and start wsl with UAC permissions works

Comment: I could uninstall and reinstall a distro with UAC and have no issues.
But without UAC mode wsl.exe simply failes and of course docker-desktop too. 
procmon does not show any eye catching errors or differences between both executions.

Comment: Please provide the WSL logs.

Comment: @Ramhound I ran the script and got a zip file with many files inside. How would I post these logs?

Comment: Can anyone please help?

Comment: @MikeSlinn - Still waiting on those logs. As there is no file upload mechanism for Stack Exchange.  You could probably upload it Github

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current WSL preview resolves this problem.
In Cmd or PowerShell, type:

```
wsl --update; wsl --update --pre-release
```

For more information, see https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/windows-subsystem-for-linux-september-2023-update/

Answer (score 1):

There is some ongoing issue with WSL.

Currently seen two working workarounds:

- run whatever you are using to start WSL as admin
- remove recent update - [details](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/10767#issuecomment-1816540839)